# Href in Javascript function using XML *closed*

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

Hi I have the following piece of code that gets the embeded url from my database and places the video within my infoWindow for my markers in my map:

```
 var x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
          x.setAttribute("src", video);
          infowincontent.appendChild(x);
```

Can someone help me in adapting this so that instead of printing a video, it instead shows a hyperlink to another website. I have the stored urls of these websites stored in my database.

I have tried the following, but to no avail:

```
 var x = document.createElement("A");
      x.setAttribute("href", url);
      infowincontent.appendChild(x);
```

Am I doing something silly?
Any help would be greatful!
Thanks

*EDIT!*

Tried the following the link is now there Thanks!

```
var x = document.createElement("A");
           var t = document.createTextNode("Festival Website");
            x.setAttribute("href", url);
            x.appendChild(t);
            infowincontent.appendChild(x);
```

Comment: You are setting the `href` but not adding any `textContent` to your anchor tag... nor is it in any way obvious what this has to do with xml...

Comment: If you have a separate question, ask a separate question: don't change this one.

Comment: Got it sorted thanks to all that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work :)

```
  var x = document.createElement("A");
           var t = document.createTextNode("Festival Website");
            x.setAttribute("href", url);
            x.appendChild(t);
            infowincontent.appendChild(x);
```